# OpenCL clFinish returning -36

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I'm completely new to OpenCL programming but have been programming in (embedded) C for years. I'm running into a problem where clFinish is returning -36, which afaik indicates some failure for the kernel to run properly. However, I can't for the the life of me figure out why. The kernel was tested to run properly in another build and the differences between the two builds seem negligible. Below is a simplified version of the code without error checking. (All return values are otherwise checked and return CL_SUCCESS)

```
#define INPUT_ARR_SIZE  128
int inArr[INPUT_ARR_SIZE];

int main()
{
    cl_uint num = 1;
    cl_int ret;
    cl_platform_id platforms[1];
    cl_device_id devices[1];
    cl_context_properties ccp[3];
    cl_context ctx;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_mem mem1, mem2;
    cl_int result;

    clGetPlatformIDs(num, platforms, &num);

    printf("%i Platforms\n", num);

    num = 1;

    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, num, devices, &num);

    printf("Devices: %d\n", num);

    ccp[0] = CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
    ccp[1] = (intptr_t)platforms[0];
    ccp[2] = 0;

    ctx = clCreateContext(ccp, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, devices[0], (cl_ulong)0, &ret);

    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &KernelSrcPtr, NULL, &ret);

    clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    printf("Build success\n");

    mem1 = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(inArr), NULL, &ret);

    mem2 = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(inArr), NULL, &ret);

    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello", &ret);

    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, mem1, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(inArr), inArr, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mem1);

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &mem2);

    cl_uint num2 = INPUT_ARR_SIZE;
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, 0, (size_t*)&num2, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret |= clFinish(queue);
}
```

And here is the kernel:

```
const char KernelSrc[] =
                "__kernel void hello(__global const int *mem1, __global int *mem2)\n"\
                "{\n"\
                "   size_t id = get_global_id(0);\n"\
                "   int intm = mem1[id] * 2;\n"\
                "   intm = intm + 5;\n"\
                "   intm = intm * 6;\n"\
                "   mem2[id] = intm / 3;\n"\
                "}\n\n";
```

Also, an interesting thing happens, where if I comment out the `mem2[id] = intm / 3;` line in the kernel, the program never finishes it's execution.

Can anyone help me with what's going on?

Comment: How do you know it is `clFinish` which returns `-36` and not `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` since you OR their results?

Comment: I tested that without the OR then put it back in once I received the result. Good catch though.

Comment: The cast from `cl_uint*` to `size_t*` in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` looks suspicious (in a 64-bit build this will probably cause problems). Why not use `size_t num2 = INPUT_ARR_SIZE;` in the first place? I use the C++ wrapper classes myself, so I'm not sure about this...

Comment: Ah, good catch, that's consistent with the behavior I've been seeing and I suppose size_t in a 64 bit machine would have to be 64 bits, whereas uint could be 32. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: I guess you have checked the validity "queue" as the error "-36" signifies "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE". Didn't you observe any errors returned till clfinish() function? There is one other way to validate the functionality of queue in your case, use clEnqueueMap & unmap instead of "clEnqueueWriteBuffer".

Comment: ThorngardSO caught it. Cast error on my 64-bit machine was causing clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to think there was a huge global work size. Thanks!